# XML Validation against XSD : cvc-complex-type.2.4.a

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, schema

Currently I am using  javax.xml.validation.Validator to validate xml against given xsd. I have set custom error handler to get all exceptions instead of exiting at the first exception.

```
Sample xsd:
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="att1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="att2"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="att3"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="att4"/>

In xml if att2 and att3 values are not there, I am getting below exception.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'att4'. One of '{"https://******":att2}' is expected.

But I need exception to be like this i.e. both att2 and att3 should be shown in expected list.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'att4'. One of '{"https://******":att2, "https://******":att3}' is expected.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As a second element, the xsd specifies **att2**, put you provided **att4**.
As a third element, the xsd specifies **att3** but you didn't provide any element.
You can try to set the elements **att2** and/or **att3** as optional with :

```
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
```

If it doesn't work, you can try :

```
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="att1"/>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="att2" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="att3" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
 <xs:element type="xs:string" name="att4"/>
```

Comment: Now it is not showing any exception at all in both cases

Answer (score 0):

The validator is implemented as a finite state machine. It computes the permitted transitions from one state to another. After reading an `att1` element, the only permitted transition is to an `att2`, and that's what it's telling you. It's not smart enough to explore the entire finite state machine and work out that at `att4` would be valid if there was an `att2` and then an `att3`.

The Saxon validator does a little better than this, but only a little: it won't give you what you're looking for here.

If it's any consolation, XSD validators generally do a lot better than regex engines (which is essentially what they are); regex engines generally just tell you that the input isn't matched by the regex, and give you no clue why.